# Ошибка collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status

Tags: c++, visual-studio-code

Хочу запустить код на C++ в VS Code. Делал всё как в документации. Когда пишу в **cmd** строку `g++ --version` всё нормально и показует версию. В path пользователя добавил **C:\msys64\mingw64\bin**.
Запускаю VS Code, создаю файл **main.cpp**, в нём пишу банальный код для вывода Hello World. Дальше **Terminal>Run Build Task...** выбираю **C/C++: gcc.exe build active file**. В терминале выскакивает ошибка **collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status**.

main.cpp

```
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    std::cout << "Hello World" << std::endl;
}
```

Терминал после запуска кода

```
> Executing task: C/C++: gcc.exe build active file <

Starting build...
C:\msys64\mingw64\bin\gcc.exe -fdiagnostics-color=always -g C:\Users\Arvil\Desktop\Nosov\main.cpp -o C:\Users\Arvil\Desktop\Nosov\main.exe
C:/msys64/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/11.2.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: C:\Users\Arvil\AppData\Local\Temp\ccrvI3MQ.o:C:\Users\Arvil\Desktop\Nosov/main.cpp:5: undefined reference to `std::basic_ostream<char, std::char_traits<char> >& std::operator<< <std::char_traits<char> >(std::basic_ostream<char, std::char_traits<char> >&, char const*)'
C:/msys64/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/11.2.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: C:\Users\Arvil\AppData\Local\Temp\ccrvI3MQ.o: in function `main':
C:\Users\Arvil\Desktop\Nosov/main.cpp:5: undefined reference to `std::ostream::operator<<(std::ostream& (*)(std::ostream&))'
C:/msys64/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/11.2.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: C:\Users\Arvil\AppData\Local\Temp\ccrvI3MQ.o:C:/msys64/mingw64/include/c++/11.2.0/iostream:74: undefined reference to `std::ios_base::Init::~Init()'
C:/msys64/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/11.2.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: C:\Users\Arvil\AppData\Local\Temp\ccrvI3MQ.o:C:/msys64/mingw64/include/c++/11.2.0/iostream:74: undefined reference to `std::ios_base::Init::Init()'
C:/msys64/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/11.2.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: C:\Users\Arvil\AppData\Local\Temp\ccrvI3MQ.o:main.cpp:(.rdata$.refptr._ZSt4endlIcSt11char_traitsIcEERSt13basic_ostreamIT_T0_ES6_[.refptr._ZSt4endlIcSt11char_traitsIcEERSt13basic_ostreamIT_T0_ES6_]+0x0): undefined reference to `std::basic_ostream<char, std::char_traits<char> >& std::endl<char, std::char_traits<char> >(std::basic_ostream<char, std::char_traits<char> >&)'
C:/msys64/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/11.2.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: C:\Users\Arvil\AppData\Local\Temp\ccrvI3MQ.o:main.cpp:(.rdata$.refptr._ZSt4cout[.refptr._ZSt4cout]+0x0): undefined reference to `std::cout'
collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status

Build finished with error(s).

Terminal will be reused by tasks, press any key to close it.
```

P.S. Не знаю имеет ли это значение, но в папке с **main.cpp** есть и другие различные файлы **.cpp**, хотя я запускал только этот. Также создавал отдельную папку только с **main.cpp** и всё равно была эта ошибка.

Comment: Запускаемый файл не является активным. Те вы запускаете то, что не в курсе о том, что его можно запускать.

Comment: чем visual studio 10,15,19,22? не угодило?

Comment: `gcc.exe` для C. `g++.exe` для C++.